# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: \' 5d41e769277c0c2ab42d2f8b\' }" at path "_id" for model "Register"

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Whenever I need to `findById` it gives the error that tells me

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: \' 5d41e769277c0c2ab42d2f8b\' }" at path "_id" for model "Register"
```

I changed my code several times but have not yet solved this:

```
route.post('/edit', (req,res)=>{
    const fullname = req.body.fullname;
    const phone = req.body.phone;
    const id = req.body._id;
    Register.findOne({_id:id})
      .then(result => {
        console.log("we findbyid the " + result);
        res.redirect("/display");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });;
    Register
      .findOneAndUpdate(id, { Fullname: fullname, PhoneNumber:phone } )
      .then(result => {
        console.log('your are update this '+result);
        res.redirect("/display");
       })
      .catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
      });
}); `enter code hereenter code here

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 5d41e769277c0c2ab42d2f8b" at path "_id" for model "Register"
```

I changed several time to like to use `findById` or some time `findByIdAndUpdate` but they cause the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a whitespace character at the first position of your id returned by **req.body._id**.

Also if **req.body._id** returns a string it must be parsed to type of **ObjectId** first.